# How do I extend a base interface dynamically?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I am using react-query and have a lot of `useQuery` hooks that accept these parameters:

```
export interface UseQueryHookProps<K> {
  client: K;
  isEnabled?: boolean;
}
```

How would I write the interface to be more generic to accept any or rather unknown additional interface/s?

So something like this:

```
export interface UseQueryHookProps<K, T> extends T {
  client: K;
  isEnabled?: boolean;
}
```

Where `UseQueryHookProps` would be called:

```
export const useGetJob = ({
  client: monitoringService,
  isEnabled = true,
  jobId,
}: UseQueryHookProps<MonitoringServiceClient, {jobId: string}>)
```

I am not sure how to write this?

Comment: Why not just write `UseQueryHookProps<MonitoringServiceClient> & {jobId: string}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to extend interface with `T`. In order to do that - `T` should be statically known.

If you want to extend `UseQueryHookProps` with `T` you should use `type` syntax instead of `interface`.

```js
export interface UseQueryHookProps<K> {
  client: K;
  isEnabled?: boolean;
}

type ExtendHookProps<K, T> = UseQueryHookProps<K> & T

interface MonitoringServiceClient {
  tag: 'MonitoringServiceClient'
}

export const useGetJob = ({
  client: monitoringService,
  isEnabled = true,
  jobId,
}: ExtendHookProps<MonitoringServiceClient, { jobId: string }>) => {

}
```

[Playground](http://tsplay.dev/N7KpDN)